# d3js heatmap graph add 3 rectangles in a group

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

Hi i am trying to customize this example

http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/raw/5558084/

I am trying to have 3 rect under a 1 hour (hour label).

```
 function (error, data) {

            console.log(data);
            var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
                .domain([0, buckets - 1, d3.max(data, function (d) {
                    return d.value;
                })])
                .range(colors);

            var cards = svg.selectAll(".hour")
                .data(data, function (d) {
                    return d.day + ':' + d.hour;
                });

            cards.append("title");

            cards.enter().append("rect")
                .attr("x", function (d) {
                    return (d.hour - 1) * gridSize;
                })
                .attr("y", function (d) {
                    return (d.day - 1) * gridSize;
                })
                .attr("rx", 4)
                .attr("ry", 4)
                .attr("class", "hour bordered")
                .attr("width", gridSize)
                .attr("height", gridSize)
                .style("fill", colors[0]).append('rect');

            cards.transition().duration(1000)
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return colorScale(d.value);
                });

            cards.select("title").text(function (d) {
                return d.value;
            });

            cards.exit().remove();
```

here is code that I tried to customize.